# workaround to skip driver signing in 64bit windows 

Tags: windows, driver, kmdf

I am an individual, not a company and i am working on a virtual kernel mode device driver. I am aware that I can test sign a driver and run in test mode. However I want to distribute my driver free of cost , but i don't have the resources to buy signature through verisign or globalsign as it is very costly and i am not earning anything through this driver .

Also test signing a driver will be a daunting task for some of the user . So i want to know is there any workaround to use the driver without signature in 64bit ?. Like run it in compatibility for 32bit , or a script that can self sign the driver on behalf of the user.

---

> **So now the question essentially is , if i distribute all the exes mentioned in this procedure and make a script to run all these
>   commands . Then can the driver be signed by the user using the
>   script?**
>
> PROCEDURE :
>
> 1.execute Inf2Cat.exe /driver:"U:\MyDriver" /os:7_X64
>
> 2.Find makecert.exe in WDK Makecert -r -pe -ss PrivateCertStore -n "CN=TestCertforWDK" TestCert.cer
>
> 3.Use Signtool.exe in WDK to sign the cat file Signtool sign /v /s PrivateCertStore /n TestCertForWDK /t
>   http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timestamp.dll
>   "U:\MyDriver\MyDriver.cat"
>
> 4.Use Signtool.exe in WDK to sign the driver Signtool sign /v /s PrivateCertStore /n TestCertForWDK /t
>   http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timestamp.dll
>   "U:\MyDriver\MyDriver.sys"
>
> 5.On test computer, import the certificate: certmgr.exe /add TestCert.cer /s /r localMachine root
>
> 6.Add it to trusted publisher list certmgr.exe /add TestCert.cer /s /r localMachine trustedpublisher
>
> 7.Verify the sign for driver Signtool verify /pa /v MyDriver.sys
>
> 8.Verify the sign for cat file Signtool verify /pa /v /c MyDriver.cat MyDriver.inf

Comment: I think you're going to be out of luck. The signing is required. Either you're going to have to buy one, or the user would if you intend self signing.

Comment: Hmm Ohk. Is it possible to write some script that does the self signing for the user ? .

Comment: I'm pretty sure 64-bit drivers have to be cross-signed with Microsoft's cert which only supports relatively few root CAs; you can't use self-signing here.

Comment: The driver ran fine when i self signed the certificate, Also test signing should be on which can be turned on using  "bcdedit.exe /set TESTSIGNING ON"

Comment: There's a reason it's called "test" signing.  Don't enable it on end user machines.

Comment: Ohk. I think It won't be a problem if i ask the users if they want to turn test-signing on . Because i don't see a pointing in paying for a opensource driver.

Comment: You don't have to sign the .sys file of your driver, because its hash is embedded in the catalog. You even break the catalog file by embedding a signature in your sys file, after you created the catalog file.

Answer (score 3):

So the answer to this question is a big fat no. I'm sorry, but unless you find a user driven workaround, or some company willing to sponsor (sign your driver) it is impossible (i mean improbable :) ). This feature has been implemented in windows to prevent the installation of them pesky rootkits.

Although it probably seems harsh, it prevents a lot of rootkits from being able to install on user machines. In fact, Microsoft recently patched a flaw related to driver signing that was allowing hackers to use microsoft's signing engine within windows to sign drivers that would be accepted by the system.

I highly doubt that you find a way to get around this programmatically. And if you do, let me know.

Comment: If he lets you know I'm sure MS will promptly patch it as it would be some sort of hack/exploit :)

Answer (score 0):

Getting the driver signed is the only proper way to get your driver on user machines and run it without hassles. You cannot expect the user to put the machine in test signing mode. I think you can refer to test signing costs to have an idea how it costs and I recommend you try to invest in that  considering your driver long term. Not sure if there has been any changes in rates.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/9a839ac3-4438-43bb-b1b8-4ed8da58ab45/how-much-does-it-cost-to-get-hck-certificates?forum=whck